# React/Next.js, panning an SVG the hard way

Tags: reactjs, svg

Trying to do an interactive floor map over here. Already seen some answers, most move on to D3.js - in case the issue is impossible to solve, will do likewise.

This gave me some pointers to start writing https://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/dmjYpR/

The code I have now:

```
const Scheme1 = function (){
  const svg = useRef(null);
  const [isPanning, setIsPanning] = useState(false);
  const [cursorPos, setCursorPos] = useState({ x:0, y:0 });
  const [newSVGPos, setNewSVGPos] = useState({ x:0, y:0 });
  const [SVGViewbox, setSVGViewbox] = useState({ x:0, y:0, width:2472.3, height: 1467.24 });

  let startPanSVG = (e) => {
    setIsPanning(true);
    setCursorPos({ x:e.clientX, y:e.clientY });
  }

  let panSVG = (e) => {
    if(!isPanning) {
      return;
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    let SVGDimensions = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    let ratio = SVGViewbox.width/SVGDimensions.width;
    let newX = SVGViewbox.x - ((e.clientX - cursorPos.x) * ratio);
    let newY = SVGViewbox.y - ((e.clientY - cursorPos.y) * ratio);
    setNewSVGPos({ x:newX, y:newY });
  }

  let stopPanSVG = () => {
    setIsPanning(false);
    setSVGViewbox({ ...SVGViewbox, x:newSVGPos.x, y:newSVGPos.y });
  }

  return (
    <svg ref={svg} viewBox={Object.values(SVGViewbox).join(" ")} onPointerDown={startPanSVG} onPointerMove={panSVG} onPointerLeave={stopPanSVG} onPointerUp={stopPanSVG} version="1.1" id="svg1003">
    ...
    </svg>
)}
```

The main issue is the SVG doesn't get dragged with the mouse during the pan, and does a rather harsh move only after `stopPanSVG` is done. Probably due to `useState` being asynchronous and triggering respectively, or having a limit on re-renders? Attempts to replace it with `useEffect` didn't go all too well - ideally I'd want it inside `startPanSVG`, so it only triggers on event, but that's against the hook's rules. Wrapping said function with the hook makes `e.clientX` undefined, even when prefixed with '?'s or skipping initial mount.

Perhaps there's a better option? Should probably add that `window`/`document`/`global` are disabled due to project settings - can't `addEventListener`, for example.

Comment: Are you aware that you are not changing the viewbox until you stop panning? In every `onPointerMove` you are just storing the current value but you are not using it to actually change the viewbox. Why don't you call `setSVGViewbox` inside `panSVG`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should fix your problem:

```
let panSVG = (e) => {
  if(!isPanning) {
    return;
  }

  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  let SVGDimensions = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let ratio = SVGViewbox.width/SVGDimensions.width;
  let newX = SVGViewbox.x - ((e.clientX - cursorPos.x) * ratio);
  let newY = SVGViewbox.y - ((e.clientY - cursorPos.y) * ratio);

  // change the viewport here
  setSVGViewbox({ ...SVGViewbox, x: newX, y: newY });
}

let stopPanSVG = () => {
  setIsPanning(false);
  // don't change viewport here
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does! Everything is being twitchy, but it works now. 
For whatever reason was absolutely certain `setSVGNewPos` was supposed to adjust the viewport. Thanks for helping (:

Comment: @alittlebyte The twitchiness will be harder to solve. You should make sure your SVG is not rendered again when only the viewport changes (e.g. memoization or plain old `PureComponent`). Also, the mouse usually generates a lot of events therefore some debouncing might help.

Comment: thank you for the tips - was also concerned by the extensive events, going to set up setTimeouts or the like

Comment: @alittlebyte [Lodash _.throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle) can solve that easily.